# Inner HTML not working:function not defined in angular2

Tags: angular, innerhtml

```
var table :HTMLTableElement = <HTMLTableElement>  
document.getElementById("test1");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
cell1.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable='true' id='newdoc'>Doctor</div>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable='true' id='newhosp'>Hospital</div>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable='true' id='costprice'>Cost price</div>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable='true' id='referralfee'>Referal price</div>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<div contenteditable='true' id='totalprice'>TotalPrice</div>";
cell6.innerHTML = '<a onclick=/"myFun();/">save</a>';

cell7.innerHTML = "<a> Cancel </a>";
```

On click function is not working as expected ,It is showing an error method not defined.Can any one suggest me what I was missing?

```
myFun(){
    alert('button clicked');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using dynamic HTML.

When you write `(click)`, it doesn't say

> Handle the click event

It says

> When you compile my code, tell Angular that it has to handle a click event

So it won't work if you use dynamic HTML. By the way, why would you do something like this ? It's cruel and gross. Can't you do it in your HTML template ?

Comment: I know it is bad idea ,but I need to add a row dynamically and save the content using web services.

Comment: You still can do that with angular ! Instead of saving the row, save its data, not the whole html. Then you get the data back, and you display the row. I mean, that's what angular is for, if you do something like this, you might as well use plain vanilla JS ...